# Does enabling default encryption on the existing s3 buckets requires any IAM change for the buckets users?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, encryption

I want to enable default encryption for the existing buckets (Amazon S3-managed encryption keys (SSE-S3)). The future objects will be encrypted but to encrypt the existing objects either I need to copy them or re-upload them.

I am wondering as I am using SSE-S3 for default encryption on the buckets, do I need to make any IAM changes to allow bucket users for accessing both the existing objects and future objects? Or enabling default encryption (SSE-S3) on buckets does not require any IAM changes as the encryption applied before storing data at rest?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using [SSE-S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/UsingServerSideEncryption.html) (Amazon S3-managed encryption keys) then you **don't have to do anything**. You may just **enforce** this encryption through bucket policy, as a default SSE-S3 bucket encryption can be overwritten by your users on per-object basis.

But if you were to choose [SSE-KMS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/specifying-kms-encryption.html) as default with your own CMK (not AWS one), then your users/inctances/lambdas would need to have permissions to access the CMK as well.